# Static class or multiple object references

Tags: class, methods, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, static-class

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application, and I have a question in regards to if I should use the exact same method in each of my classes, or use a static class with this method instead.

Here is the method:

```
public Account GetAccount(string userName)
{
    if (Session[userName] == null)
    {
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        ApplicationUser user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName).Result;
        Session[userName] = user.account;
    }
    return Session[userName] as Account;
}
```

Currently, I am adding this method to many controllers and service classes. Instead of doing this in many classes, should I just declare this method once in a static class, and use this static class whenever I want to get an `Account` object?

Are there disadvantages/advantages that I should be aware of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't duplicate code. So keep it in one place and let all other usages access that one place. Doesn't have to be static, but it could be.

Answer (score 0):

You are having multiple options, 
   Option 1: You can create one separate class and put the method in that class, that class not necessary be static.
   Option 2: You can Create Extension Method of Account Class.
   Option 3: A. For Controller create one base class like : **public class BaseController : Controller** and inherit **BaseColtroller** for all controllers and B. same for service.

Thanks
Raviranjan